# invalid classes root with buck project on android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, buck

I'm trying to add several libraries, such as fresco to a buck project. Here is the code that adds fresco:

#### `maven/BUCK`

```
### Package com.facebook.fresco:fresco
remote_file(
    name =  'com_facebook_fresco__fresco-remote',
    out = 'com_facebook_fresco__fresco-remote.aar',
    sha1 = '86df1ab4b0074e1aeceb419593d2ea6d97cdc3b4',
    url = 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/0.11.0/fresco-0.11.0.aar'
)

android_prebuilt_aar(
    name = 'com_facebook_fresco__fresco',
    aar = ':com_facebook_fresco__fresco-remote',
    deps = [
        '//maven:com_facebook_fresco__imagepipeline',
        '//maven:com_facebook_fresco__drawee',
        '//maven:com_facebook_fresco__imagepipeline-base',
        '//maven:com_parse_bolts__bolts-tasks',
        '//maven:com_android_support__support-v4',
        '//maven:com_nineoldandroids__library',
        '//maven:com_facebook_fresco__fbcore',
    ],
    visibility = ['PUBLIC']
)
```

Here is for example a file generated by `buck project --ide INTELLIJ`:

#### `.idea/libraries/library_maven_com_facebook_fresco__fresco.xml`

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="library_maven_com_facebook_fresco__fresco">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/buck-out/gen/maven/com_facebook_fresco__fresco-remote/com_facebook_fresco__fresco-remote.aar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

The aar file exists in said dir.

But I get `invalid classes root`

[image: alt]

Full project https://github.com/vinz243/snappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Buck with the new Android project generation.  You can get the old one by passing `--deprecated-ij-generation` when you invoke `buck project`.

You should probably file an issue for this, however :)